# What is the web tracking standard/API called?

Tags: javascript, http, web, browser, tracking

A few years ago I read about a new browser API that allows for posting web tracking data (analytics/logging/ad impressions) in a standardized way. The data posting is asynchronous, works even after the page is closed and the browser could be configured to not send it at all.

I now fail to find the technology that I seem to remember. What is that technology called?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the web beacon API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

Comment: @Andy Tracking happens whether you like it or not. It seems to be a good idea to do it in a clean way that power users can cleanly disable. Also from a business perspective, this makes sense. When you're being payed or you run a business this is what you gotta do :)

Comment: @Squiggs. yea, that's it. Thank you.

Comment: have posted comment as Answer so I can grab rep if that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for the web beacon API developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API